# Preform a Segue from AlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to segue to another view controller once the Ok button is clicked in an alert view.  This is what I have so far.

```
- (IBAction)cancelScripting:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *cancelScriptingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are You Sure" message:@"This action will cancel your observation" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


[cancelScriptingAlert show];

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 1) {


       [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"CRHViewController" sender: self];

    }
}
```

I dont know what I am doing when it comes to [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];  The view controller I want to segue to is called CRHViewController.  I feel like there is another method that I need or I need to import CRHViewController.h or something.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: have you set the segue in the storyboard? are you sure that you've set the alertView's delegate and that alerView:clickedButtonAtIndex gets called?

Comment: I ran an nslog and the clickedButtonAtIndex does get called. as for setting the segue in the storyboard, I am not sure I know what you mean by that? I also dont know what you mean by the alertView's delegate.  I am super new at this stuff.

Comment: What type of segue is that ? Because if it's 'push' you probably already made sure that your controller showing the alert is part of a UINavigationViewController. For a quick test, try to change the segue 'modal' and see if it works.